# Evaluate c# code as string in a aspx file

Tags: c#, string

I have this problem: From a database, held up a string, which contains HTML mixed with C# code. I wish I could run correctly both codes on my page .aspx.

e.g.
in my .aspx:

```
<div><%= Model.repo.getCode() %></div>
```

and the getCode() method give me this:

```
<div id="secondDiv"><p><%= Model.Person.Name %></p></div>
```

so I want the final html file look like:

```
<div><div id="secondDiv"><p>Jhon</p></div></div>
```

any suggestion?

Comment: A very good question! I thing you need expressions

Comment: Why can't you inject the value of Model.Person.Name into the HTML inside of the getCode method?

Comment: Is the code simple (Property evaluation or something like that?)

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I thought the same thing as why you want to use binding expressions if the binding doesn't occur in design-time but in run-time....

Comment: What's the story of `Model.Person.Name`?

Comment: Nice question, I think you need to create a dynamic ASPX page (even if something good may be done with DLINQ and/or expressions I can't figure out something simple enough). Take a look to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107234/how-to-create-a-aspx-page-dynamically-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

There may be direct way to bind such value,
But if you could store *String.Formatable* into database then it would be easy to bind the data needed.

Using [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) you achieve like,

returned string from Model.repo.getCode() (**see curly braces**)

```
    "<div id="secondDiv"><p>{0}</p></div>";
```

And in ASP code,

```
    <div><%= string.format(Model.repo.getCode(),Model.Person.Name) %></div>
```

Comment: I suppose he gets everything from databse then he doesn't know if he'll need Model.Person.Name or something else...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this project as it helped me with a similar problem: https://github.com/formosatek/dotliquid Basically you can bind whatever objects to a template and that template can call properties of you objects and even use conditional logic and loops.